angular ngx-extended-pdf-viewer not preview the file
I'm working on a .NET project that includes protected PDF files. I've made them accessible by adding a query string containing a token. The link looks like this: https://example.com/Resources/file.pdf?token=token
When opening the link in a browser, it opens the file.
I've deployed the project on an Ubuntu server.
I've also created an Angular project and installed a library for previewing PDF files called ngx-extended-pdf-viewer.
When I preview the file using this library, it works on localhost.
However, when I upload it to the server, it doesn't work.
When I check the console, it shows "blocked".
That is the angular code:
          <ngx-extended-pdf-viewer [src]="previewService.getProtectedUrl(fileSrc)" [useBrowserLocale]="true"></ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>

these 3 errors:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://example.com/path/file.pdf?token=user_Token.  (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)
An error occurred while loading the PDF.
PDF.js v3.10.557 (build: cb0a59411)
Message: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. >> from this file >> viewer-3.10.557.min.js
Uncaught (in promise)  Object { message: "NetworkError when attempting
to fetch resource.", name: "UnknownErrorException", details:
"TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.", stack:
"BaseExceptionClosure@https:// here long error message


when I click on Learn More, I got: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed?utm_source=devtools&utm_medium=firefox-cors-errors&utm_campaign=default

I have update the question, and put a screenshot for error in console

I  have tried this link from browser: https://example.com/path/file.pdf?token=user_Token. and It worked

you mean just give user a link to the pdf file, and when click on the link, It will open at new tab?

Thank you, but I want to know where the problem is. As I mentioned earlier, the file preview works on localhost..
Is the problem related to how files work on Ubuntu, or is the query string being removed at some point? or what?

Thanks. But how can this help me
